# Adding an integer ID to ASP.NET Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

In the standard forms authentication, users are identified by a Guid. I want to give my users an UserId of type int (doesn't have to be the primary key, just something to do lookup's on).

Is it safe to add an additional column to the aspnet_users table, or should I create a new table which FKs to the UserId column and has a Unique column which generates the integer ID?

The later sounds like a bad performance hit to take just for the sake of an int!

**EDIT** 
I want to create URLs like those on stackoverflow. eg. https://stackoverflow.com/users/23590/greg-b where the User ID is an int. For that reason I don't want to use Guids.

Comment: Does the membership API not offer the particular type of lookup you're looking for?

Comment: @IrishChieftain is that a genuine question or a hint? Cheers

Comment: Hi Greg, genuine question - normally I wouldn't be looking up a member by their ID so I was trying to get a handle on exactly what it is you were doing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create profiles and store the associated urlID there. Web Forms don't have Profiles available out of the box, but you can see a workaround here:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/01/ASPNET-Web-Site-versus-Web-Application-Project.aspx

The advantage of using Profiles is that you can tap into all the existing logic and won't have to write as much custom code yourself, aside from constructing the URL.

You could combine this with [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) for friendly URLs, if you're using ASP.NET 3.5 or up.

**UPDATE:** kinda similar question:

[Shorter GUID using CRC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184441/shorter-guid-using-crc)

Comment: How would I generate the Unique integer to store in the profile.

Comment: Create the profile and add some arbitrary field like age. Then see if there is an auto-generated int id created in the profile table?

Comment: AFAIK, Profiles creates a Profiles.ProfileID int key for you which you can retrieve via the Users.UserName